# Change color of two parts of string when using String.format()

Tags: android, string.format

I am using the following to show the remaining time in a word game app.

```
remainingTime.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"REMAINING TIME: %d MNS %d SECONDS ",(millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60 ,(millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60));
```

I want to change the color of the minute and second text. How can the colors be defined in their placeholders??

I want it look like this:
 [image]

Comment: Either you need to use `SpannableString` or set the text using `Html.fromHtml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. What I did was find the numbers using regex and used 
Spannable in the while loop of the matches.find() to color the index of the matches. The start was the index and the end index + 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin you can do it with an Extension Function.

```
    fun TextView.setColouredSpan(word: String, color: Int) {
        val spannableString = SpannableString(text)
        val start = text.indexOf(word)
        val end = text.indexOf(word) + word.length
        try {
            spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(color), start, end,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            text = spannableString
        } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
         println("'$word' was not not found in TextView text")
    }
}
```

Use it after you have set your text to the TextView like so

```
private val blueberry by lazy { getColor(R.color.blueberry) }

textViewTip.setColouredSpan("Warning", blueberry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get the Digits in a different color

```java
public SpannableString getColoredString(String string, int color){

        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(string);

        for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
            if(Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))){
                spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), i, i+1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
        return spannableString;
    }
```

In your Activity code use the above function and set the return value to the textview

```java
String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"REMAINING TIME: %d MNS %d SECONDS ",(millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60 ,(millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);

SpannableString string = getColoredString(text, Color.YELLOW);

remainingTime.setText(string);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some sort of "some text email@test.com some text".
Where email@test.com had to be with different color.

I tried:

```
<string name="myText">
some text
<font color="#FFFFFF">%1$s</font>
some text
</string>
```

But it looks like after getString, HtmlCompat ignores "font color", so that's why I used symbols "<" and ">" as usual symbols like that:

```
<string name="myText">
some text
&lt;font color="#FFFFFF"&gt; %1$s&lt;/font&gt;
some text
</string>
```

After that everything showed up nicely as I needed:

```
val email = "email@test.com"
val text = getString(R.string.myText, email)

binding.textView.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(text, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```